# Python+Flask: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, flask

I am from Java world and new to python and so to Flask. Here is my views.py

```
from app import app

class Employee:
    def __init__(id,name): self.id = id; self.name = name;

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return Employee(12345,"MyName")
```

In the function index(), when i tried to return "Hello World" without class Employee in the file and run the server, Hello World string was written to the webpage.

I then thought of outputting a json,

```
{"id":"12345","name":"MyName"}
```

So I started to introduce a class Employee and created a constructor to pass id and name.

Unfortunately it started showing this error.

> File "C:\python\microblog\app\views.py", line 9, in index    return
>   Employee(12345,"MyName")

By the way, here i assume that if I can get rid of the error, flask would be able to convert the object to json by taking it as default mimetype for objects.

I had look at these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596549/python-init-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given), but didn't help with my knowledge.

Comment: `__init__` should have `self` as it's first argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first argument on `__init__` you must pass self:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id,name): 
       self.id = id; self.name = name;
```

Because `self` it's ref ob object Employee.
Every Python object has two special method: `__new__` and `__init__`. The first method for create object, it hasn't ref on object (self) and the second for initialise created object so it has ref named self.

Answer (score 4):

Python "methods" are really functions and no pointer to the current instance is magically inserted in the function's scope, so you have to declare your first argument as a reference to the current instance (by convention this argument is named `self`) - or as a reference to the current class if it's a `classmethod` (and then the first argument is - by convention - named `cls`).

When the function name is looked up on an instance, it's turned into a (callable) `method` object that keeps a reference to both the function and the current instance and inserts the instance as the first argument to the function call, as explained here : https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod - so you dont have (and must not) explicitely pass the current instance when calling the method.

NB : I understand this might seems weird (and worse) coming from the Java world, but there are actually quite a few good reasons for this peculiar design, as you'll probably find out by yourself when you'll start exploring the dynamic programming / metaprogramming part of Python.